# Reference for the algorithm to find the intersection between a subspace and positive orthant

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, linear-programming

I came across this algorithm, in this question [Algorithm for the intersection of a vector subspace with a cone of non-negative vectors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80609/algorithm-for-the-intersection-of-a-vector-subspace-with-a-cone-of-non-negative#comment916762_80609) ;
Is there any reference for the algorithm described in the question?